# Select single row with DataFrame.loc[] without index

Tags: pandas

Assuming I have a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["house", "red"], ["car", "blue"]], columns=["item", "colour"])
```

What is the idiomatic way to return a single row, or raise an exception if exactly one row is not found, using `DataFrame.loc`:

```py
match = df.loc[df["colour"] == "red"]]
# I know there is exactly one row in the resulting DataFrame
# TODO: How to make match to return a single row as pd.Series
```

This would be similar to SQLAlchemy's `Query.one()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) and [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) that the output is a Series (or use a test if you don't want to raise an exception):

```
match = df.loc[df["colour"] == "red"].squeeze()

assert isinstance(match, pd.Series)
```

alternative to `assert`:

```
if isinstance(match, pd.Series):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```